# How to generate separate jar files for application, source, and documentation (for central.sonatype.org)

Tags: java, scala, maven, jar, sbt

Sonatype has a repository that I want to deploy a jar file to, and they ask for separate files for application, sources, and javadocs:

Example:

```
example-application-1.4.7.pom
example-application-1.4.7.jar
example-application-1.4.7-sources.jar
example-application-1.4.7-javadoc.jar
```

In Scala SBT, I have a command called "package" that generates the jar file for the project, but that only generates "example-application-1.4.7.jar".

**Question**: What should I do to generate the other two jar files?

Comment: In maven you would use the `javadoc` and `sources` plugin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with maven.

Comment: You multi-tagged Maven and SBT. You need to provide details about your build for us to recommend suitable changes.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to release your application with the `maven-release-plugin`. This plugin will generate all of those side artifacts for you.

Comment: The OP has never typed the "maven" command in the terminal, but the OP would be willing to learn https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/ in order to release his jar file using the instructions specified in: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html

Answer (score 3):

In Maven, in order to get the additional `-sources` and `-javadoc` artifacts, add to your POM file the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- additional plugin configurations, if any.. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the snippet above:

- We are invoking the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/examples/configureplugin.html) to create an additional jar files for sources
- We are invoking the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) to create an additional jar files for javadoc

Executing

```
mvn clean package
```

You will find these two additional jars in the `target` folder.

---

The `.pom` file instead is generated during the `install` phase, but it is not placed under the `target` folder. Basically, it is a copy of your `pom.xml` file, with a different extension and used by Maven during the dependency mediation process to check which transitive dependencies are required by the concerned artifact.

Executing

```
mvn clean install
```

Maven will install the artifact in your local cache (in your machine), under `path_to_cache/.m2/repository/your_groupId/your_artifactId/your_version/`. In this folder, you will also find the `.pom` file, which normally you don't need to distribute (it is created automatically by Maven).

---

Further note: you probably don't want to generate these additional jar files at each and every build, so to speed up normal builds and have them only on demand, you could wrap the snippet above in a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

You can achieve this by removing the snippet above from your `build` section and add a further section at the end of your pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prepare-distribution</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

So that normal builds would not create these jars anymore, but when executing the following:

```
mvn clean install -Pprepare-distribution
```

You would instead get them back. the `-P` option is actually activating on demand the profile defined with the id `prepare-distribution`.

---

With Maven 3 a default profile already comes as part of the [super pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) which perform exactly the same actions (sources and javadoc artifact), hence no need to add anything to your existing project. Simply run:

```
mvn clean install -Prelease-profile
```

Or, to activate it via a property

```
mvn clean install -DperformRelease=true
```

However, as also specified in the super pom, this profile may be removed in future releases (although there since first Maven **3** version till version **3.3.9** so far)

> NOTE: The release profile will be removed from future versions of the super POM

The main reason behind this warning is most probably to push for the usage of the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), which indirectly makes use of this profile via the [`useReleaseProfile`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#useReleaseProfile) option of the [`release:perform`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) goal.

---

As highlighted by comments, if you are not familiar with maven (especially via console) I would definitely recommend to

- Go through the official [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) documentation for a quick but worthy look.
- Play with Maven from the command line, is there where Maven gives you its best. IDE integrations are great, but command line is the real turning point.
- Then play with the POM customization above, to get familiar with some concepts and behaviors, first directly as part of your default build, then moved to a profile.
- Then, and only then, move to the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin) usage. I recommend it as last step because you would already have acquired more confidence and understanding and see it as less magic and more reasonable approach.

Comment: The `maven-release-plugin` does all of that by default. I think the OP wants to _release_, not strictly _deploy_ (in Maven terms).

Comment: Umm... the OP wants to put his Scala SBT library in a place where people can add it to their projects without having to specify some non-default repo host/location. The OP is not yet familiar with the command line tool Maven as he relies on IntelliJ.